# Converting from UTC into date format in R

Tags: r, timezone

I have a UTC timestamp. I want to convert it into YYYY/MM/DD format in `R`.

For example, `1318394558766`. I tried `format` command unsuccessfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct` or `as.POSIXlt`.  However you have to know the origin date from which your number of milliseconds started.

```
as.POSIXct(1318394558766/1000, origin='1970-01-01')

> unlist(as.POSIXlt(1318394558766/1000, origin='1970-01-01'))
    sec     min    hour    mday     mon    year    wday    yday   isdst 
 38.766  42.000  21.000  11.000   9.000 111.000   2.000 283.000   1.000 
>
```

Then you can use `format` to get the desired YYYY/MM/DD:

```
format(as.POSIXct(1318394558766/1000, origin='1970-01-01'), format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution is to use `.POSIXct`:

```
utc <- .POSIXct(1318394558766/1000, tz="UTC")
```

Then you can easily convert `utc` to a Date or character vector:

```
as.Date(utc)            # Date vector
format(utc, "%Y-%m-d")  # character vector
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Justin's answer (and because I can't make comments) you may want to add the tz to the transformation.

```
as.POSIXct(1318394558766/1000, origin='1970-01-01')
[1] "2011-10-12 05:42:38 EST"
as.POSIXct(1318394558766/1000, origin='1970-01-01', tz="UTC")
[1] "2011-10-12 04:42:38 UTC"
```

For more information see;

```
?timezone
```

Comment: +1 I once was surprised to find NAs in my time values. Turned out I had values for the hour that does not exist, if you change to daylight saving time.