# how to convert a timestamp into string (without changing timezone)?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, timestamp, sparklyr

I have some unix times that I convert to timestamps in `sparklyr` and for some reasons I also need to convert them into strings.

Unfortunately, it seems that during the conversion to string `hive` converts to EST (my locale).

```
df_new <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "/mypath/parquet_*",
                             overwrite = TRUE,
                             name = "df_new",
                             memory = FALSE,
                             options = list(mergeSchema = "true"))
> df_new %>%  
           mutate(unix_t = from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC'),
           date_str = date_format(unix_t, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'),
           date_alt = to_date(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC'))) %>% 
    select(t, unix_t, date_str, date_alt) %>% head(5)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
# Database: spark_connection
            t unix_t              date_str                date_alt  
        <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>                   <date>    
1 1419547405. 2014-12-25 22:43:25 2014-12-25 17:43:25 EST 2014-12-25
2 1418469714. 2014-12-13 11:21:54 2014-12-13 06:21:54 EST 2014-12-13
3 1419126103. 2014-12-21 01:41:43 2014-12-20 20:41:43 EST 2014-12-20
4 1419389856. 2014-12-24 02:57:36 2014-12-23 21:57:36 EST 2014-12-23
5 1418271811. 2014-12-11 04:23:31 2014-12-10 23:23:31 EST 2014-12-10
```

As you can see both `date_str` and `date_alt` use the `EST` timezone. I need `UTC` here. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Look up POSIXct. Also, I'm pretty sure the format strings for months and minutes are the other way around. You may want to double check

Comment: we are talking abour spark here, right?

Comment: This could be of interest; https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237811

Comment: thanks but are you sure this works in sparklyr? i am not talking about base R here

Comment: are you really using `sparklyr` and not `SparkR` here?

Comment: this is sparklyr

Comment: the latest version

Comment: How about posting output of `dput(df_new)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Hive function reference, [date_format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) uses Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which I believe always defaults to the JVM time zone, this explains why this gets you a character string converted to your time zone.

One option is to detect the time zone and manually add the hours to get UTC.

Another option would be to use `lubridate` with `spark_apply()`:

```
sdf_len(sc, 1) %>%
  mutate(unix_t = from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(1522371003) , 'UDT')) %>%
  spark_apply(
    function(e) {
      dplyr::mutate(
        e,
        time_str = as.character(
          lubridate::with_tz(
            as.POSIXct(unix_t, origin="1970-01-01"),
            "GMT"
          )
        )
      )
    },
    columns = c("id", "unix_t", "time_str"))
```

Comment: wonderful!!! it works! funnily enough, after the `spark_apply` the column `unix_t` is now a `double` (whereas it was a `dttm` before)

Comment: what is perhaps puzzling is that also `to_date` seems to use the timezones locale...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that sparklyr is doing some weird translation of timezones into the hive functions. I'd try registering the dataframe as a table and doing the manipulation with pure HQL:

```
createOrReplaceTempView(df_new, "df_new")
result <- sql("select from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC'),
   cast(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as STRING),
   cast(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as DATE)
   from df_new")
head(result)
```

**edit**

If you're unfamiliar with SQL-languages, you can add any of the variables from `df_new` as a comma separated list like so (and rename your selections with `as`)

```
select var1, var2, t,
   from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as unix_t,
   cast(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as STRING) as date_str,
   cast(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as DATE) as date_alt
   from df_new
```

You can also use * to represent all variables from the data frame:

```
select *,
   from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as unix_t,
   cast(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as STRING) as date_str,
   cast(from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(t) ,'UTC') as DATE) as date_alt
   from df_new
```

Comment: do you know how can I use these SQL `cast` directly in the mutate above?

Comment: I believe all of the casting in mutate has to be done through R functions, and that those are the source of the issue, which is why I suggest using HQL to do this particular manipulation. Is there a reason it needs to be in the mutate?

Comment: thanks, i dont need the mutate, but i do need all the other variable as well in the same table.

Comment: you can add them to the select. If you're unfamiliar with SQL, I'll edit to show how.

Answer (score -1):

Try using as.POSIXct() ?

```
format(as.POSIXct(unix_t, origin = unix_t, tz = "UTC", usetz=TRUE),"%Y-%m-%d %H:mm:ss")
```

This will first convert unix timestamp to UTC and then formatted to desired string.

Comment: does not work. this is not regular R, this is Sparklyr!