# Convert String to timestamp in Sparklyr

Tags: r, string, date, sparklyr

I'd like to convert String to time stamp, I used the below code but it added 4 hours to the timestamp, I really appreciate if you could help me to figure it out the issue

I used Sparklyr.

```r
fds<- fds %>%  
  mutate(time2 = from_unixtime(
    unix_timestamp(transaction_time, "yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
fds<- fds %>% mutate(transaction_time_2 = to_timestamp(time2))
```

`transaction_time` is string with this format `'2018-05-3016:00:40'` 
by using `from_unixtime`, it has been converted to '`'2018-05-30 16:00:40'` and by using `to_timestamp` it has been converted to `2018-05-30 20:00:40`. everything is correct except 20 hour, I still expected 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, I think it relates to the timezone settings
try the following at the top of your program, then the problem should disappear:

```
sparklyr::invoke_static(sc, "java.util.TimeZone",  "getTimeZone", "GMT") %>%
  sparklyr::invoke_static(sc, "java.util.TimeZone", "setDefault", .)
```

check out this answer for more details :

[changing the JVM timezone in sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333052/changing-the-jvm-timezone-in-sparklyr)

Comment: thanks for your help, it worked @Mouad_S

Comment: This was a lifesaver, thank you! None of the other solutions in similar questions seemed to work like this did.