# How to use lubridate::round_date for sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, lubridate, sparklyr

I am looking for truncating datetimes to minutes, hours, etc. Something like lubridate::round_date is very helpful. But I cant use this with sparklyr?

```
Undefined function: 'round_date'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ‒ see [Why can't I use double colon operator with dplyr when the dataset is in sparklyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52972504/10465355).

The right way to do it is to use of the built-in Spark SQL functions.

```r
# For the sake of reproducibility
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/52365367/10465355
spark_session(sc) %>% 
  invoke("conf") %>% 
  invoke("set", "spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")

options(tibble.width = 120)

df <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(
  ts = c("2019-01-08 23:21:15", "2020-02-06 13:14:00")
)) %>% mutate(ts = to_timestamp(ts))

df
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
  ts                 
  <dttm>             
1 2019-01-08 23:21:15
2 2020-02-06 13:14:00
```

```r
df %>% 
  transmute(
     year = date_trunc("year", ts),
     month = date_trunc("month", ts),
     day = date_trunc("day", ts),
     hour = date_trunc("hour", ts),
     minute = date_trunc("minute", ts)
  )
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 5]
  year                month               day                
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-08 00:00:00
2 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-02-01 00:00:00 2020-02-06 00:00:00
  hour                minute             
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2019-01-08 23:00:00 2019-01-08 23:21:00
2 2020-02-06 13:00:00 2020-02-06 13:14:00
```

No additional import or 3rd party libraries are required.

Comment: It looks like the `date_trunc` function is no longer implemented in Sparklyr (as of version 2.4.3). To do this I had to resort to an SQL query with `DATE_TRUNC` through the DBI package.